# Use older version of Mule CE ESB with AnypoinyStudio

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio

**Summary**
Is it possible to use AnypointStudio together with an older version of Mule ESB Community edition, more precisely Mule ESB CE 3.3.x?

**Longer description**
I have a server running on Mule CE 3.3.1, and I need to do development on the project. The old version of Mule Studio that used 3.3.1 CE is no longer available. I've been in touch with Mulesoft directly, and they don't have any old build of Mule Studio available either.

The newer Anypoint Studio allows you to download an older version of the ESB and use that instead. However, the download site that adds a new runtime to the Studio only has versions 3.5 and 3.4 as choices. The 3.3.1 ESB is available as a separate download on Mulesoft's site, but I'm not sure how to integrate this with the Studio properly.

So:

- Is there some way to use the Anypoint Studio together with ESB 3.3.x CE, or
- Is there somewhere I can find an older version of MuleStudio which uses ESB 3.3.x, or
- Do I have to migrate my project to ESB 3.4 CE and update the server in order to set up a new development environment for it?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it there is no other solution than using an older MuleStudio. The container bundles that Studio uses are not exactly the standalone version of Mule. They do contain extra stuff to help Studio to understand the DSL, how to start/stop, etc.

Every new version of Studio supports a number of old versions of the ESB, but not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

As Victor said, you cannot use Anypoint Studio with older versions. But you could try [Mule IDE](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Installing+Mule+ESB+3+and+the+Mule+IDE) that was the IDE for those old versions. For sure it won't be as nice as Anypoint Studio, but you can give a try.

Comment: Mule IDE seems to be for even older versions, 3.2.X. I think I would need Mule Studio (basically the same as Anypoint Studio) but there are no old downloads available on Mulesoft's site, nor do they have them available anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of MuleStudio are listed in the link:

http://mule-studio-releases.s3.amazonaws.com/

Just copy the  and append it to the above URL to download the file

Example:
http://mule-studio-releases.s3.amazonaws.com/1.3.1-01-GA-CE/MuleStudio-CE-for-macosx-64bit-1.3.1-201209061215.zip

Answer (score 0):

Click on Install New Software -> Work With (select drop down) ->Mule ESB Runtimes for Anypoint Studio.

You can see older versions of Mule Runtime.
Install them and use them in your project configuration.